# Avoid circular reference in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I would like to calculate price including risks. The problem is that I would like to avoid circular reference. Is there any way to avoid enabling "iterative calculation"?

Basically I need to calculate Price in B9 and it is `=(B1+B4)/(1-B7)`

where B4 is `=B9*B2`

[image]

Result with iterative calculation" enabled:

[image]

Comment: Short of using vba or the solver, there is no method to do this without circular references.

Comment: Solver is not an option because installation of plugins is not allowed. What could be VBA solution?

Comment: Your logic in calculating risk is incorrect. Risk cost calculations are generally calculated directly from costs before sales margins are added. If your formula in B4`=B1*B2`, the price is calculated correctly. Your total price comes out to be $1,262.50. Anytime you run into a circular reference situation, it's your calculation logic that's off, not the formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter the economical method you're using to calculate the risk (I'm not an economist), without the help of the `Solver` or `VBA`, the only way to do this is constructing an iterations table. The more expanded the table is, the more exact the solution will be...

[image: Iterations table]

Just place:

On cell `D5`: `=($A2+D4)/(1-$A6)`

On cell `E4`: `=$A4*D5`

and drag the formulas to the end of the table (horizontally).